# Github Site name not correct

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm testing out grit with github io and it's making the site 
`sitename.github.io/repository-name` instead of `sitename.github.io` . How can I change it to that easier format? The git site wasn't too clear on that. Here is the repository that uses the grit blogging framework:

```
https://github.com/testykle/testykle
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://pages.github.com/ :

> Create a repository
>   Head over to GitHub and create a new repository named username.github.io, where username is your username (or organization name) on GitHub.
>   If the first part of the repository doesn’t exactly match your username, it won’t work, so make sure to get it right.

Change the name of your repository to testykle.github.io

**Update**
Further, the particular repository you are forking does not have a `master` branch. [User & Organization pages need to be on the master branch](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages).

After you create a master branch, you should see your testykle.github.io soon.

Comment: I had tried that before. I guess I'll give it some time to see if the site will load. http://testykle.github.io/

Comment: Updated answer - you need to create a master branch.